# How to start a background process for a file generation api

Tags: excel, spring, multithreading

I am returning the result of an API under the form ModelAndView which is basically an excel file. Due to long processing of this api, I want to move the processing "process" in the background using the help of threads. Is there any way you can help me out to rewrite this controller method in order to activate a background thread that performs the processing? Thank you so much.

My controller class looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/background")
public class BackgroundController {

    private final BackgroundService backgroundService;

    public BackgroundController(BackgroundService backgroundService) {
        this.backgroundService = backgroundService;
    }


    @ApiOperation("Get excel file from processing")
    @GetMapping("/headers/export-excel")
    private ModelAndView getExcelFile(Principal principal,
                                      @RequestParam(name = "reqId", required = false) BigDecimal reqId) {
        return new ModelAndView(new ExcelView(), ExcelView.EXPORT_LIST_NAME, backgroundService.getExcelFile(reqId));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the effect you're trying to achieve? Can the excel processing be parallelized somehow? Otherwise, there's no point in just running the process in another thread, as the controller method must wait for the result anyway

Comment: Let's say i want to start a procedure that takes 30 minutes, I do not want it to make freeze on response until the execution is done. And when the execution is done, it will notify the user somehow, that`s not important how.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

Comment: seems like what i want. thanks